# Probability density function of a transformed variate

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

If I have a random variate $Y$ with probability density function

$P(x) = \frac{1}{2\Gamma(1+1/\alpha)}e^{-|x|^\alpha}, \quad x \in (-\infty, \infty)$

and I transform the variate $Y$ as $Y'=Y\sigma+\mu$, what is the probability density function of $Y'$?

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Comment: It's not my downvote, but I think it's because of the homework clause: "which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it".

Comment: Homework? Thanks, but I already have my degree. I'm not that familiar with statistics, that's why I asked the question. This is why this site exists, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a linear transformation of the random variable; just apply scale and shift to the probability density function:

$$P_{Y'}(z) = \Big\lvert \frac 1 \sigma\Big\rvert P_Y\Big(\frac{z-\mu}{\sigma}\Big)$$